# PHP array_filter with arguments

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
function lower_than_10($i) {
    return ($i < 10);
}
```

that I can use to filter an array like this:

```
$arr = array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$new_arr = array_filter($arr, 'lower_than_10');
```

How can I add arguments to lower_than_10 so that it also accepts the number to check against? Like, if I have this:

```
function lower_than($i, $num) {
    return ($i < $num);
}
```

how to call it from array_filter passing 10 to $num or whatever number?

Comment: See also the scope canonical: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/2943403)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As an alternative to @Charles's [solution using closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments/5483102#5483102), you can actually find an example [in the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#89384) on the documentation page. **The idea is that you create an object with the desired state (`$num`) and the callback method (taking `$i` as an argument):**

```
class LowerThanFilter {
        private $num;

        function __construct($num) {
                $this->num = $num;
        }

        function isLower($i) {
                return $i < $this->num;
        }
}
```

Usage ([demo](http://www.ideone.com/jdXWw)):

```
$arr = array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$matches = array_filter($arr, array(new LowerThanFilter(12), 'isLower'));
print_r($matches);
```

---

As a sidenote, you can now replace `LowerThanFilter` with a more generic `NumericComparisonFilter` with methods like `isLower`, `isGreater`, `isEqual` etc. Just a thought — and a [demo](http://www.ideone.com/TYvw4)...

Comment: Good workaround. For the sake of maintainable code, it might help to modify the class to support more readable method calls as well:

$matches = $myobj->ArraySelect( Array('from'=>$arr, 'where'=>$foo, 'lessthan'=>12 ) )

Comment: I am not a php savy, so maybe this is an obvious question, but how can you pass in an array to array_filter and still make it work? the documentation never talks about this, except for someone's comment.

Comment: @NicolaPedretti I assume you're talking about the seconds argument to `array_filter`? It's simply a `callable`; in the above case matching "Type 3: Object method call": `array(<instance>, <method-name>)`, cf. [PHP: Callbacks / Callables - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Interesting. It does feel really hacky to me. Passing the method directly seems more intuitive.

Comment: @nicolapedretti I haven't touched PHP for several years. By now most of it feels hacky to me :)

Comment: Ok, so what when you want one argument more? In other words, this solution works for exactly 2 arguments?

Comment: @nights If I get you right: `array_filter($arr, array(new BetweenFilter(9, 12), 'isBetween'))` with `class BetweenFilter { private $lower; private $upper; … function isBetween($input) { return $input >= $this->lower && $input <= $this->upper; }}`. Bounds are inclusive in this (untested!) example.

Comment: what if the `isLower` requires 2 or three params? how would you specify those extra 2 params from within the `array_filter`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Sorry to say, but I haven't touched PHP since writing this answer. Your question may be better suited as a separate thread.

Answer (score 355):

if you are using php 5.3 and above, you can use [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to simplify your code:

```
$NUM = 5;
$items = array(1, 4, 5, 8, 0, 6);
$filteredItems = array_filter($items, function($elem) use($NUM){
    return $elem < $NUM;
});
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use the `use` word to provide the lambda with extra parameters. Thanks for such a valuable hint! :)

Comment: This is in my opinion the best solution. It's simple and to the point. It's a shame that PHP doesn't allow anonymous functions to use variables declared in the parent scope, like in javascript.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted solution, as it is the only one that answers the question: *"how can add arguments to array_filter"*. The other answers are providing alternative routes to the same result, using either closure or classes.

Comment: Take note that you can use multiple variables in the 3rd parameter, just separate each variable by a comma such that ``use($NUM, $var2)``

Answer (score 39):

In PHP 5.3 or better, you can use a [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
function create_lower_than($number = 10) {
// The "use" here binds $number to the function at declare time.
// This means that whenever $number appears inside the anonymous
// function, it will have the value it had when the anonymous
// function was declared.
    return function($test) use($number) { return $test < $number; };
}

// We created this with a ten by default.  Let's test.
$lt_10 = create_lower_than();
var_dump($lt_10(9)); // True
var_dump($lt_10(10)); // False
var_dump($lt_10(11)); // False

// Let's try a specific value.
$lt_15 = create_lower_than(15);
var_dump($lt_15(13)); // True
var_dump($lt_15(14)); // True
var_dump($lt_15(15)); // False
var_dump($lt_15(16)); // False

// The creation of the less-than-15 hasn't disrupted our less-than-10:
var_dump($lt_10(9)); // Still true
var_dump($lt_10(10)); // Still false
var_dump($lt_10(11)); // Still false

// We can simply pass the anonymous function anywhere that a
// 'callback' PHP type is expected, such as in array_filter:
$arr = array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$new_arr = array_filter($arr, $lt_10);
print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it is neat, but i have php 5.2 on the server, so i'm bound to use jensgram's :)

Comment: In php < 5.3 you could use `create_function()`.

Comment: `create_function()` is basically `eval()` with another name, and is just as evil.  Using it should be discouraged.  The wacky class-based workaround given in the accepted answer is a better solution than using `create_function()` in this case.

Answer (score 29):

if you need multiple parameters to be passed to the function, you may append them to the use statement using ",":

```
$r = array_filter($anArray, function($anElement) use ($a, $b, $c){
    //function body where you may use $anElement, $a, $b and $c
});
```

Answer (score 14):

In extension to [jensgram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments/5483168#5483168) answer you can add some more magic by using the [`__invoke()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke) magic method.

```
class LowerThanFilter {
    private $num;

    public function __construct($num) {
        $this->num = $num;
    }

    public function isLower($i) {
        return $i < $this->num;
    }

    function __invoke($i) {
        return $this->isLower($i);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do

```
$arr = array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$matches = array_filter($arr, new LowerThanFilter(12));
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 7):

Worth noting that since PHP 7.4 [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) are available, and this can be done even more neatly:

```
$max = 10;
$arr = array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$new_arr = array_filter($arr, fn ($n) => $n < $max);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class ArraySearcher{

const OPERATOR_EQUALS = '==';
const OPERATOR_GREATERTHAN = '>';
const OPERATOR_LOWERTHAN = '<'; 
const OPERATOR_NOT = '!=';      

private $_field;
private $_operation;
private $_val;

public function __construct($field,$operation,$num) {
    $this->_field = $field;
    $this->_operation = $operation;
    $this->_val = $num;
}


function __invoke($i) {
    switch($this->_operation){
        case '==':
            return $i[$this->_field] == $this->_val;
        break;

        case '>':
            return $i[$this->_field] > $this->_val;
        break;

        case '<':
            return $i[$this->_field] < $this->_val;
        break;

        case '!=':
            return $i[$this->_field] != $this->_val;
        break;
    }
}


}
```

This allows you to filter items in multidimensional arrays:

```
$users = array();
$users[] = array('email' => 'user1@email.com','name' => 'Robert');
$users[] = array('email' => 'user2@email.com','name' => 'Carl');
$users[] = array('email' => 'user3@email.com','name' => 'Robert');

//Print all users called 'Robert'
print_r( array_filter($users, new ArraySearcher('name',ArraySearcher::OPERATOR_EQUALS,'Robert')) );
```