# Search a 2d array by one column value and return another value from the qualifying row

Tags: php, arrays, filter, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array such as:

```
$arr[] = array("id" => 11, "name" => "First");
$arr[] = array("id" => 52, "name" => "Second");
$arr[] = array("id" => 6, "name" => "Third");
$arr[] = array("id" => 43, "name" => "Fourth");
```

I would like to get the name correspondent to a certain ID so that I can do:

```
$name = findNameFromID(43);
```

and get, for instance, "Fourth".

I thought of using `array_filter` but I am a bit stuck on how to correctly pass a variable. I have seen questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments) but I don't seem to be able to extend the solution to a multidimensional array.

Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
findNameFromID($array,$ID) {
     return array_values(array_filter($array, function($arrayValue) use($ID) { return $arrayValue['id'] == $ID; } ));
}

$name = findNameFromID($arr,43);
if (count($name) > 0) {
    $name = $name[0]['name'];
} else {
    echo 'No match found';
}
```

PHP 5.3.0 and above

**EDIT**

or variant:

```
findNameFromID($array,$ID) {
    $results = array_values(array_filter($array, function($arrayValue) use($ID) { return $arrayValue['id'] == $ID; } ));
    if (count($results) > 0) {
        return $name[0]['name'];
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

$name = findNameFromID($arr,43);
if (!$name) {
    echo 'No match found';
}
```

**EDIT #2**

And from PHP 5.5, we can use [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
findNameFromID($array, $ID) {
    $results = array_column($array, 'name', 'id');
    return (isset($results[$ID])) ? $results[$ID] : FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'd bother to declare a custom function for such a basic task.  Restructure the 2d array into an associative map, then attempt to access the map data with the search value as the key.  Fallback to `null` if the element is not found.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kYBTj))

```
$find = 43;
var_export(
    array_column($arr, 'name', 'id')[$find] ?? null
);
```