# Return rows from multidimensional array based on value of an element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$arr_ramones = array(
          1=>array('name'=>'johnny', 'display'=>1), 
          2=>array('name'=>'joey', 'display'=>1), 
          3=>array('name'=>'cj', 'display'=>0), 
          4=>array('name'=>'deedee', 'display'=>1), 
          5=>array('name'=>'marky', 'display'=>0)
  );
```

I'd like to loop through my array but only with rows that have a display value of 1.

I read how to do this with a [regular array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071780/array-filter-and-multidimensional-array).  Can something similar be done with multidimensional arrays without costing performance?  My example array is small - real world example contains thousands of values.

Comment: If the 'real world' example array would contain `thousands of values` then really it should be held in a database, you would then be able to filter them as they are requested from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

also works with [array_filter](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php).

```
$arr_ramones = array(
    1 => array('name'=>'johnny', 'display'=>1), 
    2 => array('name'=>'joey', 'display'=>1), 
    3 => array('name'=>'cj', 'display'=>0), 
    4 => array('name'=>'deedee', 'display'=>1), 
    5 => array('name'=>'marky', 'display'=>0)
);
$filter = array_filter($arr_ramones, function($arr) {
    return $arr['display'] == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
foreach ($arr_ramones as $item) {
  if ($item['display']) {
    echo $item['name'];
  }
}
```

or use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$display = array_filter($arr_ramones, function($item){
  return $item['display'];
});

foreach ($display as $item) {
  echo $item['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) if you just want to display data without creating new array. In case of creating array use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
array_walk($arr_ramones, function($a) { // displaying information from array based on requirements
    if ( $a['display'] == 1) {
        echo $a['name'] . " "; // johnny joey deedee 
    }
});

$n = array_map(function($a) { // creating new array based on requirements
    if ( $a['display'] == 1) {
        return $a['name'];
    }
}, $arr_ramones);
```

Comment: Is there a performance benefit in using `array_walk` as opposed to `foreach`?

Comment: @acoder With performance they are pretty much the same while this function's algorithm uses loop as well, though it has another benefits. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `foreach` like this.

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr)
{
 if($arr['display']==1)
  {
    echo $arr['name']."<br>";
  }
}
```

Using an `array_filter`

```
function filt($var)
{
   return $var['display']==1;
}  

$new_arr=array_filter ($arr_ramones,"filt" );
print_r($new_arr);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/130787)

Comment: Right, that came to mind immediately.  Wondered if there is a function to essentially "query" the array.. so I could get a count of values having display=1.

Comment: @acoder, `array_filter` can be used too as shown in the illustration. I would prefer a `foreach` instead.