# PHP "remove from array where" operation

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say you have a php array filled with dictionaries/associative arrays of first and last names, like so:

```
$userList = array(array('first'=>'Jim', 'last'=>'Kirk'), array('first'=>'George', 'last'=>'Bush'));
/*
$userList now looks like
{
    {
        first => Jim,
        last => Kirk
    },
    {
        first => George,
        last => Bush
    }
}
*/
```

How do I tell php to `"Remove elements from $userList as $users where $user['first'] === 'George'"`?

Comment: I make a function `removeByWhere` in my answer, you can try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it (based on "Charles"'s answer from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments))...

First, I created a function-factory:

```
function createNotNamedFunction($first)
{
    return function($user) use($first) { 
        return $user['first'] !== $first;
    };
}
```

Then, I call it when I need to filter the array:

```
$first = 'George';
$notNamed = self::createNotNamedFunction($first);
$filteredUsers = array_filter($userList, $notNamed);
```

**Short**, **simple to understand**, **extensible** (the test can be arbitrarily complex since it's a first-class function), and **doesn't involve loops**.

This technique uses *closures*, `array_filter`, and only works in `PHP 5.3` or greater, but it's what I would consider the canonical answer.  It turns out that `array_filter` **is** "remove from array where" when you provide it with an arbitrary test.

Thanks to all world-class php wizards who contributed alternative patterns!

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` and use a reference `&` to be able to modify / unset that array element:

```
foreach($userList as &$user) {
    if($user['first'] == 'George') {
        unset($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to remove the first name, but the whole user.

Comment: Intriguing.  So, you're just "unset"ing variables inside the array, without ever telling the array, and that works and doesn't cause a crash?

Comment: This is very common and the reason they added the reference to the `foreach`.  Just saw your answer (WOW), can't say that I would build a *function* to return a *closure* and run it through `array_filter`.  Actually, I can say, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a callback with the conditions you want

Comment: This is the short version of what I consider the right answer, thanks Matt.