# create LIKE friendly string from space separated sentence

Tags: php, mysql

I want to allow my users to search values in the database using partial words in any order, so that this searched string :

```
nan mu
```

would return any string where both `nan` and `mu` are contained, in any order. with only two bits, it is rather easy with `array_filter()` and the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments) answer to create the strings

```
%nan%mu%
%mu%nan%
```

so that mysql will search for those. Now I have a problem when there are more then two bits, such as `nan mu te`. the purpose is to obtain those strings:

```
$string1 = %nan%mu%te%
$string2 = %nan%te%mu%
$string3 = %mu%nan%te%
$string4 = %mu%te%nan%
$string5 = %te%nan%mu%
$string6 = %te%mu%nan%
```

and make 6 mysql `LIKE` condition `WHERE Field LIKE $string1 AND Field LIKE $string2 ...` so that any possibility of those three bits in any order will be contained in the result

for those about to complain about sql injection, thanks, but no thanks, I use PDO and parameterized queries.

my actual try with string `nan mu te`:

```
class EstDefini
 {private $STR;
  function __construct($vSTR)
   {$this->STR = $vSTR;}
  function Verifier($vSTR)
    {return !($vSTR == $this->STR);}}

$vString = 'nan mu te';

$aBits = explode(' ',$vString);
$vNb = count($aBits);

for ($i=0;$i<$vNb;$i++)
 {$vAppend = implode('%',array_filter($aBits,array(new EstDefini($aBits[$i]),'Verifier')));
  $aLiterals[$i] = '%' . $aBits[$i] . '%' . $vAppend;}
```

returns only 3 strings, because my initial count is only three (there are three bits from my exploded string): (this is `var_dump($aLiterals)`)

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "%nan%mu%te"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "%mu%nan%te"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "%te%nan%mu"
}
```

my initial tought is to modify the count:

```
$vNb = $vNb * max($vNb-1,1);
```

and try and shuffle the other bits to obtain the different `LIKE` friendly strings but then since my initial `$aBits` array is still of size 3, this class creation call `new EstDefini($aBits[$i])` will try and access undefined bits.

**How to create `LIKE` friendly strings from space separated words with the purpose of finding all those words in any order with MySQL?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the approach is a little wrong - why do you need to check if it's `field LIKE '%a%b%' OR field LIKE '%b%a%'` when you could instead just check if it's `field LIKE '%a%' AND field LIKE '%b%'` and cover both.

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$params = array_fill(0, count($words), '(?)');
$search = implode(' AND field LIKE ', $params);
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE $search");

$query->execute(array_map($words, function($word) { return '%' . $word . '%'; }));
```

Comment: +1 I would just comment on the over complex check. Very nice solution with the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Explode said string into array:

```
$array = explode(" ", $string);
```

After that you can make a string for the query like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE (";
```

Then add the variables like so:

```
$query .= "" . $array[0] . " OR "; //Or there for multiple strings.
```

Then end the string queue with:

```
$query .= ")";
```

Probably not the most effective way but will get the job done. If I need to elaborate more please comment.

Comment: this won't work: I don't want strings containing only one of the bits to be returned, which is what will happen with a or clause

Comment: Do you have a limit on seach lenght?