# Undefined variable inside PHP array_filter

Tags: php, array-filter

this could be a very silly question but I just can't understand how PHP scope is working on this piece of code:

```
$leagueKey = 'NFL';
$response['response'] = array_filter($response['response'], function($tier){
    return ($tier['LeagueKey'] === $leagueKey ? true : false);
});
```

When I run that, I get an "Undefined variable: leagueKey" exception. On the other hand, this works perfectly well:

```
$response['response'] = array_filter($response['response'], function($tier){
    return ($tier['LeagueKey'] === 'NFL' ? true : false);
});
```

Why can't PHP see my $leagueKey variable inside the array_filter function?

Thanks!

Comment: because `$leagueKey` is defined outside of that function. In order to use it you could use `global $leagueKey` inside your anonymous function but it's not the best of ways

Comment: Because it's out of scope, just like any function, you would have to feed an outside argument into it. `$leagueKey` is outside of the function, the string `'NFL'` is in, so it works.

Comment: try this $response['response'] = array_filter($response['response'], function($tier) *use $leagueKey*  {
    return ($tier['LeagueKey'] === $leagueKey ? true : false);
});

Comment: Shouldnt be marked as duplicate.... This is a good question and different than the other one. Just a similar answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your `$leagueKey` variable is outside the scope of the anonymous function (closure). Luckily, PHP provides a very simple way to bring variables into scope - the `use` keyword. Try:

```
$leagueKey = 'NFL';
$response['response'] = array_filter($response['response'], function($tier) use ($leagueKey) {
    return $tier['LeagueKey'] === $leagueKey;
});
```

This is just telling your anonymous function to "use" the `$leagueKey` variable from the current scope.

*Edit*

Exciting PHP 7.4 update - we can now use "short closures" to write functions that don't have their own scope. The example can now be written like this (in PHP 7.4):

```
$response['response'] = array_filter(
    $response['response'], 
    fn($tier) => $tier['LeagueKey'] === $leagueKey
);
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
$response['response'] = array_filter($response['response'], function($tier) use ($leagueKey) {
 return ($tier['LeagueKey'] === $leagueKey ? true : false); 
});
```

Comment: You are missing parens, `use ($leagueKey)`.

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen thanks, it won't work without brackets

Answer (score 2):

This is how the scope of all the variables work. Your anonymous function doesn't know anything about variables outside of it. This holds for all kind of functions: if you need to use a variable that is outside of a function - you pass it to the function. In this case you can't pass it anything, but if you are running PHP5.3+ you can do 
`function($tier) use ($leagueKey){`
which will tell the function that it needs to use $leagueKey defined outside of it. If your php is lower than 5.3 you'll have to use workaround like this one: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments)

Answer (score -4):

try globals vairable:

```
$GLOBALS['leagueKey'] = 'NFL';
$response['response'] = array_filter($response['response'], function($tier){
    return ($tier['LeagueKey'] === $leagueKey ? true : false);
});
```

Comment: Using global is not a good practice check this for clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why