# php array filter with custom arguments

Tags: php, arrays

```
     Array
(
    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => click
            [timestamp] => 2017-05-09T18:00:41+00:00
            [url] => https://xxxxx.xxx/xxx/sdfsdfsd
            [title] => download e-book
        )
     [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => click
            [timestamp] => 2017-05-09T18:00:41+00:00
            [url] => https://xxxxx.xxx/xxx/sdfsdfsd
            [title] => download e-book
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => open
            [timestamp] => 2017-05-09T18:00:21+00:00
            [url] => https://yyyyyyy.yyy
            [title] => download e-book
        )

)
```

I have used this function to filter array

```
function filter_callback($element) {
    if (isset($element->action) && $element->action == 'click') {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

function filter_callback1($element) {
    if (isset($element->url) && $element->url == 'https://yyyyy.yyy') {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

should be able to send

> 'https://yyyyy.yyy' ,url, click, action
>   to function

How to combine these two functions into one function such that I can send action and URL to this function and fetch the correct result

Comment: what's the problem in using the two comparisons in one function? that'll be `combining` them right?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma yes i need to combine these function into one function

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments

Comment: just merge the two conditions ? does that work ?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma` if (isset($element->action) && $element->action == 'click' isset($element->url) && $element->url == 'https://yyyyy.yyy')) { return TRUE; } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an anonymous function instead of a defined function if you want to pass values into the scope of the callback.

```
array_filter($your_array, function($element) use ($action, $url) {
    return isset($element->action, $element->url)
        && $element->action == $action
        && $element->url == $url;
});
```