# Finding values in second array if specific key from first array is found

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have written a code, that finds value in second array if it finds specific key from first array, but my question is - is it possible to do it better? for example without 3 loops ?

For example here are keys and values to search for, which user has checked at form and submitted ($tegoszukamy):

```
array (
  'kolor' => 
     array (
       0 => 'bialy',
       1 => 'zielony',
  ),
  'rozmiar' => 
     array (
       0 => '60',
       1 => '70',
  ),
  'rozdzielczość' => 
     array (
       0 => '1200x1800',
  ),
  'moc' => 
     array (
       0 => '500W',
  ),
);
```

Here is array with products IDs where searching is performed ($tuszukamy):

```
array (
  47 => 
    array (
      'rozmiar' => '50,60,70,80,90,100',
      'kolor' => 'bialy,czarny',
  ),
  48 => 
    array (
      'rozmiar' => 'L,M,XS,S,L',
      'kolor' => 'zielony,niebieski,czerwony,zolty,bialy,czarny',
  ),
  49 => 
    array (
      'rozdzielczość' => '1200x1800',
      'prędkość' => '60str/min',
  )
)
```

Here is my code that is working fine:

```
foreach ($tegoszukamy as $atrybut=>$wartosci_szukane) {
    foreach ($tuszukamy as $numer_posta=>$wartosci_zbioru ) {

        if (array_key_exists($atrybut, $wartosci_zbioru) !== FALSE){

            foreach ($wartosci_szukane as $ws) {
                if (strpos($wartosci_zbioru[$atrybut],$ws) !== FALSE) {
                    echo 
                        'We have found'
                        .$ws.
                        'in'
                        .$wartosci_zbioru[$atrybut].
                        'where product id is'
                        .$numer_posta.
                        ''
                        ;}                      
                else {
                    echo 
                    'We found not'
                    .$ws.
                    'in'
                    .$wartosci_zbioru[$atrybut].
                    ''
                    ;}
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do it better/with better code performance/speed, because I dont know if these 3 loops will be good when user filters through eg. 10000 products.

Comment: `!== FALSE` after `array_key_exists` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following alternatives:

1.

```
class Subject {
private $attr_name;
private $attr_values;

function __construct($attr_name, $attr_values) {
    $this->attr_name = $attr_name;
    $this->attr_values = $attr_values;
}

public function check($key, $item) {
    $found = array();

    if (isset($item[$this->attr_name])) {
        foreach($this->attr_values as $val) {
            strstr($item[$this->attr_name], $val) && array_push($found, $val);
        }
    }

    count($found) > 0 ? 
        $message = "Found attribute <u>" . $this->attr_name . "</u> with value <b>" . implode(", ", $found) . "</b> in ID: " . $key . "."
        : 
        $message = "No matches for <u>" . $this->attr_name . "</u> found in ID: " . $key;

    return $message;
}
}

foreach ($tegoszukamy as $attr_name=>$attr_values) {
$filtered = array_map(array(new Subject($attr_name, $attr_values), "check"), array_keys($tuszukamy), $tuszukamy);
foreach($filtered as $result) {
    echo $result . '<br>';
}
}
```

2.

```
foreach ($tegoszukamy as $attr_name=>$attr_values) {
    $filtered = array_filter($tuszukamy, function ($item, $key) use($attr_name, $attr_values) {
    $found = array();

    if (isset($item[$attr_name])) {
        // var_dump($item[$attr_name]);
        foreach($attr_values as $val) {
            strstr($item[$attr_name], $val) && array_push($found, $val);
        }
    }

    count($found) > 0 ? 
    $message = "Found attribute <u>" . $attr_name . "</u> with value <b>" . implode(", ", $found) . "</b> in ID: " . $key . "."
    : 
    $message = "No matches for <u>" . $attr_name . "</u> found in ID: " . $key;

    echo $message . "<br>";

    return count($found) > 0;

}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

// something to do with $filtered;
}
```

I'm not sure whether either of them is faster than yours. I'll leave the testing to you. :)

The first one was inspired by jensgram's answer to this question: [PHP array_filter with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments)